# drupal 7 restrict role access for one single node

Tags: drupal-7, hook, roles

I have set up a site with role access permissions for different node types.
For just one node, I have to remove de access permissions for just one single role, the others will stay unchanged. 
Because the site has already installed many modules I prefer to use only a hook function instead of a module as nodeaccess or content access.
Can somebody please advise for the hook script?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, adjust operation, user role and node type as needed:

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
    if (in_array('the role', $account->roles) && $op == 'view' && $node->type == 'article' && $node->nid == 42) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
}
}
```

You could leave out $op and $node->type in the conditional statement if this is just for a single nid.

[Documentation for hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)

Comment: Dear Doodero
thank you very much for your answer.
I would like to use this for authenticated users, other user roles are allowed to have acces. I tried authenticated as role but this seems not to work. Is authenticated not a real role??